# Как отправлять уведомление wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Есть тема wordpress, все уже готово кроме одного. Как получить уведомление содержащие `url` сайта на котором активирована данная тема?
Уведомление нужно получать на почту или если можно, то другим способом

Comment: Чтобы знать какие сайты можно будет взломать? ;)

Comment: Нет, нужно для рассылки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить хук на `after_setup_theme` или `switch_theme` и тем же `wp_mail` например отправить письмо.

например:

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options');

function mytheme_setup_options () {
   wp_mail(параметры, отсылки, письма)
}
```